# removing left hand side parenthesis in str_split in r

Tags: regex, r, strsplit, stringr

How can I make this work in R?

```
str_split("U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)",pattern=' (')
```

**Error in gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)", fixed = FALSE,  : 
  invalid regular expression '(', reason 'Missing ')''**

```
gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)")
```

**Error in gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)") : 
  invalid regular expression '(', reason 'Missing ')''**

```
gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)",perl=T)
```

**Error in gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)", perl = T) : 
  invalid regular expression '('**

In addition, warning message:

```
In gregexpr("(", "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)", perl = T) :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
    'missing )'
    at ''
```

Comment: Is the problem you haven't escaped the parenthesis: `pattern = "\\("`? Parentheses are special in regex.

Comment: Do you speak about `strsplit` function when you write `str_split` in your first example?

Comment: Could you add the output expected in your question to undersannd better what you want?

Answer (score 2):

To split using a special character like"(" you have to escape it. To escape a regular expression in R, you have to use a double "\", one for the R character string and another one for the regular expression, as suggested by Hugh. Then your pattern should be "\(". See the [regex doc](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) for more information.

The following code does the job

```
raw_string <- "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)"
splitted_string <- strsplit(x=raw_string, split="\\(")

splitted_string

#[[1]]
#[1] "U.S. "                              
#[2] "California, San Luis Obispo County)"
```

But I'm not sure that's what you want. If your goal is to remove the left-hand side parenthesis in your character string, use `gsub` with an empty replacement pattern.

```
raw_string <- "U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)"
no_parenthesis_string <- gsub(pattern="\\(", replacement="", x= raw_string)
no_parenthesis_string 
# [1] "U.S. California, San Luis Obispo County)"
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("\\\\(","",c("U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)"))
```

or

```
paste0(strsplit(c("U.S. (California, San Luis Obispo County)"), "\\(")[[1]], collapse = "")
```

Answer:
**"U.S. California, San Luis Obispo County)"**